# Using machine learning to optimize parameter scores

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, association-rules

I have a dataset containing fraud and non fraudulent data. The system in place is a rule based engine with over 20 rules. If the total score is above a certain threshold the payment is classified as fraudulent. 
What would be an effective way of using machine learning to optimize the assigned score to the different rules(fraud rules).

Thanks

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that removes most of its useful information.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classification problem. You have 20 features (I.e., rules) and output is binary (I.e., fraud or no fraud). It is not clear what the rule features are. It sounds like they might be binary (e.g., pass or fail). Do you have training data on which items are actually fraud and which are not? If so, you can train classification model. For example, you could perform logistic regression to predict probability of fraud with your rules as inputs. The coefficients assigned to each rule could be interpreted as the scores or weights for each rule. If the predicted probability of fraud  is above some probability threshold you would classify as fraud.

If you do not have training data you can attempt to cluster similar rule results into two clusters.

EDIT:
If you can define some loss function (e.g., accuracy of predictions) then you can set up an optimization problem to find the best coefficients (I.e., those that minimize error metric). This is just an optimization problem and suitable solvers are available depending on your coding language. However, your method of weighted rules will likely not perform as well as established classification methods.

Comment: Seems more like a non supervised than supervised...